# splitting an string list with proper aligning the string elements

Tags: javascript

Example `Company 1,company ltd 2,company, Inc.,company Nine nine, ltd,company ew` So here is example of the string,  I want to split it like that it consider `Company 1` as one company and `company, Inc.` as one, but here got situation in `company, Inc.` it condidering 2 companies while this logic. how can I resolve this? Lke with such strings `company, Inc.` I want to consider it one element only

```
        const company = company.split(",");
```

Here the string can be anything, this is just example for the string, but it can be any name. So I am looking for generic logic which works for any string, having same structure of string.

**Note $ ==(,) represents as separation point, kept to get clarity that from that point I need to separate the string**

Object: 
Example 1

```
 { 
    _id: 5de4debcccea611e4d14d4d5
    companies: One Bros. Inc. & Might Bros. Dist. Corp.$Pages, Inc.$Google Inc. Search$Aphabet Inc. tech.
    }
```

Example 2

```
{
_id: 5de4debccc333611e4d14d4f5
companies: Google Comp. Inc.$Google Comp. Inc. Estd.$Tree, Ltd.$Tree, Ltd.
}
```

Comment: Strange string. No way to split it like you want. At least no simple way to do that.

Comment: If you have possibility to alter data to be "Company 1; company ltd2" i would suggest doing that. otherwise the only possibility i see is going through list in pairs and checking for special cases. like if  [i+1] == "Inc." join [i] and [i+1]

Comment: Do you have control over the string/data?  You could put quotes around the strings and then split on `',`

Comment: How did you created this string ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut this string I am getting as response from api call, perhaps this string is example, it can be anything but having same structure of string.

Comment: @Nandani: saying `anything` should be logical or in some proper format, you can put some logic in creating this sting/api response. you should return as object/json from api response.

Comment: @NikleshRaut I am getting this string list in return of API call as object

Comment: @Nandani: ok then please share that object ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut updated question with update

Comment: @Nandani: Can you change separator string from `,` to any other symbol  ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut updated with $ as sepration point

Comment: @Nandani: If `$` is not reserved in react then it's okay, you will solve you problem otherwise you can use multiple character like `&sp` as separator

Comment: @NikleshRaut I didn't get you. its just for ref. I won't change that response in any way

Comment: @Nandani: Your situation is limited and restricted. Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

First I split on 'ompany' rather than 'company', because you have one instance of 'Company' with a capital C -- see the output of the first console log within a comment below.

Then I put things back together using reduce -- map is *not* the right choice here, as I need an array that is one fewer than the size of the fragments I generated.  Then though since I need an array that corresponds to the number of strings we want to return, which is one fewer than the number of fragments, the first thing I do inside my reduce is ensure I do not look beyond the end of the array.

Then I split each fragment and pop off the last element, which just puts either "C" or "c" back together with "ompany".  Then I replace any trailing ',c' from the *next* fragment with an empty string, and add the result to the company.  Finally I add the entire result to the array I'm generating with reduce.  See comment results at bottom.  Also here it is on repl.it: https://repl.it/@dexygen/splitOnCompanyStringLiteral

This is a fairly concise way to do this but again if you can do anything to improve your data, you won't have to use such unnecessarily complicated code.

```
    const companiesStr = "Company 1,company ltd 2,company, Inc.,company Nine nine, ltd,company ew";
    const companySuffixFragments = companiesStr.split("ompany");

    console.log(companySuffixFragments);
    /*
    [ 'C', ' 1,c', ' ltd 2,c', ', Inc.,c', ' Nine nine, ltd,c', ' ew' ]
    */

const companiesArr = companySuffixFragments.reduce((companies, fragment, index, origArr) => {
  if (index < companySuffixFragments.length - 1) {
    let company = fragment.split(',').pop() + 'ompany' 
    company = company + origArr[index + 1].replace(/,c$/, ''); 
    companies.push(company);
  }
  return companies
}, []);

    console.log(companiesArr);

    /*
    [ 'Company 1',
      'company ltd 2',
      'company, Inc.',
      'company Nine nine, ltd',
      'company ew' ]
    */
```

Comment: In this string is an example, it canbe any thing, not only company, it can be anything..

Answer (score 0):

As has been commented I'd try to get a more clean String so that you don't have to write "strange" code to get what you need.

If you can't do that right now this code should solve your problem:

```
let string = 'Company 1,company ltd 2,company, Inc.,company Nine nine, ltd,company 
ew';
let array = string.split(',');

const filterFnc = (array) => {
let newArr = [],
    i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i].toLowerCase().indexOf('company') !== -1) {
        newArr.push(array[i]);
    } else {
        newArr.splice(newArr.length - 1, 1, `${array[i - 1]}, ${array[i]}`);
    }
}

return newArr;
};

let filteredArray = filterFnc(array);
```

Comment: I'm working on a solution too.  You should maybe consider commenting on how yours works, it's a good practice when answering.

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm relatively new to stackoverflow. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: You can edit your question, if you've never done so before, it will be a good exercise.  Thanks for participating

Comment: I am looking for generic solution which works for any string with same structure

Answer (score 0):

try with the below solution.

```
var str = ["company 1","company ltd 2","company", "Inc.","company Nine nine", "ltd","company ews"];
var str2 =str.toString()
var str3 = str2.split("company")
function myFunction(item, index,arr){if(item !=""){let var2 = item.replace(/,/g," ");var2 = "Company"+var2;arr[index]=var2;} }
str3.forEach(myFunction)
```

OUtput:

```
str3
(6) ["", "Company 1 ", "Company ltd 2 ", "Company Inc. ", "Company Nine nine ltd ", "Company ews"]
```

And remove the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

First change `,` with any other symbol. I am using `&` here and then split string with `,`

```js
var str= 'Company 1,company ltd 2,company, Inc.,company Nine nine, ltd,company ew';
str = str.replace(', Inc.','& Inc.');
/*str = str.replace(', ltd','& ltd');*/
console.log(str.split(',').map((e)=>{return e.replace('&',',').trim()}));
```

Comment: Here `company Nine nine, ltd` in this `ltd` is coming in seprately

Comment: If you want `ltd` separately then remove this like `str = str.replace(', ltd','& ltd');`

Comment: @Nandani: Now `ltd` is separate, Is this you wanted to do ?

Comment: here I am looking for generic solution, Like string can be any name, not just this static string.

Comment: @Nandani: How you are creating this string, may be you can put your logic there.

Comment: This string I am reading from API call from mongo db, and getting this company response. and then I render this to react `<GridList>` component